# how can I get value from google spreadsheet

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular, google-sheets

I need to get value from Google spreadsheet iframe, only one cell (A2) that I display on website.

This value (10%) I want to transfer to progress bar (`style="width: [value from google spreadsheet]"`).
Is it possible?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I've add API and it works very well, I can show values in CMD, so now I want to get this value and transfer to my website. Any suggestions?

```js
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

function printInfo(my_sheet){
    console.log(`Name: ${my_sheet.kontrahent}`);
}


async function accessSpreadsheet() {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('ID');
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[4];

    console.log(`Title: ${sheet.title}, Rows: ${sheet.rowCount}`);


    const rows = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
       offset: 1 
    });

    console.log(rows[0].kontrahent); <!--I want get this value and transfer it to my div progress bar on HTML -->
  
     rows.forEach(row => {
        printInfo(row)
     });


    }

accessSpreadsheet();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>My test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vST98KwaC1TPrCA-I-t7DrtL6dcjiFt1K1300c2j57N-SbcYRA2r4akTE_QxuStIvky39bedioEx-Tr/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;range=A2&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false&amp;chrome=false" height="40px" width="226px"></iframe>
  
  
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 80%"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research effort as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome. As Rubén notes, it's always good to share what you've tried and let others know that you're not just using the community to do your work for you, but you've explored what's possible and got stuck. What you are trying to do, retrieve a value from a Google Spreadsheet can certainly be done -- but you need to use the Google Spreadsheets API. Have a look at the example google provides for doing exactly what you're trying to do here. (Other than getting it from the iframe -- you won't fetch it from there, but from the spreadsheet itself).

Comment: Actually I thinking about how can I starting with this problem.
I need some tips. I've create simply app in angular and I want to show some values ​​from google docs spread sheet, so I publish my sheet and I choose range to get this value. Now I try to get this value and transfer it to my progress bar, and really I don't know how can I start. I think some examples will be very usefull for me

Answer (score 1):

iFrame interaction is kinda complicated and unsafe. A better way to tackle this problem is using the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).

Here is the basic reading section: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading

You would need the following components:

1. Google API key
2. Something to do a basic REST request

Comment: API is required? Can I get this value without API?

Comment: @szczepan19 I think it is the easiest way. So you are using angular, as I read above. Try to read about the angular HttpClient and services. Also, try to add tags "angular" to the question, as this is angular related.

Comment: Now I have the Google API key, any suggestions how I should do a basic REST request?